# Maximum number of Vumarks Element that can be generated

Tags: augmented-reality, vuforia

I have to generate a Vumark that carries out the numeric type encoding and I would like to understand what is the maximum limit of Vumark that I can generate with the various ID-Lengths.
I haven't found a specific reference in the documentation.

What is the maximum ID-Length value and the maximum number of markers that can be generated?

I did a test with ID-Length 8 and in the Vuforia Target Manager I get a MaxID equal to 255.
Setting the ID length to 9 results in a MAXID of 406.
I need to understand how the ID Length and the maximum number of markers that can be generated are related.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When using the VuMark illustrator script (https://library.vuforia.com/design-guide/designing-vumark-adobe-illustrator#setup-script) you get a dialog like the one below. In the Numeric case, you have to enter the Maximum ID and "Maximum ID"+1 is  the maximum number of available distinctive markers.

Below, the number of elements required indicates how many elements the template should have. This number is higher than the minimum 9 ( 2^9 = 511 > (406+1) ) as the Vumark uses the extra bits for error correction and other base information.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Do you know which is the max value for ID-Length?

Comment: From this documentation "https://library.vuforia.com/web-api/vumark-generation-web-api" the ID-Length is the number of bits necessary to encode the numeric ID. So "Maximum ID" < 2^"ID-Length" - 1. For example if you have 8 bits then the max ID is 255, for 9 bits is 511... etc. Thus for 406, 8 bits are not enough (255 < 406) but 9 bits are 406 < 512. As mentioned in my answer "ID-Length" < "number of elements" due to error correction.

Comment: I had a further look at the various APIs and my conclusion is that for 'numeric' type you can completely ignore the ID Length (which is somewhat confusingly defined in bits). The 'Maximum ID' fully defines the number of unique VuMarks you can generate.